# Shared Element Transition Glitch for GridView items

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop, android-transitions

I have the following situation:

1) I have an Activity A with a GridView showing thumbnails of images.

2) I have another Activity B which has only a PhotoView ([link](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)) matched with its parent's size.

3) When I click on any item on the GridView the small thumbnail should animate from its current position and size and change to the size of the image in the PhotoView.

**Screenshot**

[image: Activity A with the GridView]
[image: Activity B with the PhotoView]

**My Implementation**

This is what I did for the permission,

```
<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>        
<item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
<item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>

<!-- specify shared element transitions -->
<item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">
    @transition/change_image_transform</item>
<item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">
    @transition/change_image_transform</item>
```

And this is my transition file. Hope this is correct according to my specifications,

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <changeImageTransform/>
    <changeBounds/>
    <changeTransform/>
</transitionSet>
```

This is where I am getting the view and setting the transition name,

```
View photo = (View) list.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.fileThumb);
                    photo.setTransitionName("photo" + position);
                    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), Pair.create(photo, photo.getTransitionName()));

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GalleryActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(Config.GALLERY_EXTRA, position);
                    getActivity().startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

In in my Activity B (with just the PhotoView fully),

```
final PhotoView photoView = new PhotoView(container.getContext());
                    relativeLayout.addView(photoView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
photoView.setTransitionName("position"+pos);
```

**The Problem**

The animation works but nowhere close to expected. Its not smooth at all and glitchy. What am I doing wrong? I hope anywhere here can catch my mistake and improve it.

Example - QuickPic app, Sony Album app.

Comment: Since your transition is functioning, that indicates that the connections are properly made between the two activities. Glitches can be caused by a few different things. Can you post a screen recording of the problem? (You can capture it in Android Studio)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old question and you probably found a solution already but from what I can see it looks like you use different transitionNames ("position" + pos vs. "photo" + pos). Is this working at all?

The second thing which comes to my mind is that loading a image into an image view is resource consuming so maybe you would need to load it asynchronously and use a postponeEnterTransition so that the second activity can load the image properly before staring the animation.

However, I'm a newbie to android animations so thats just a guess and my 2 cents. Hopefully I'm not completely wrong and this answer will help somebody :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I haven't tried it in quite a while now.